# Why os.rename refuses to work with this varible formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to move files in current directory root (found in `rootfiles`, each into their own directory, where the directory name is generated from the filename.

```
for f in rootfiles:
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.splitext(f)[0]):
        os.makedirs(os.path.splitext(f)[0])
        os.rename(f, os.path.splitext(f)[0]\f)
```

My problem is the `os.rename` part. I think my code would translate to `os.rename(filename.ext, filename\filename.ext)`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `os.path.splitext(f)[0]\f` be more like `os.path.splitext(f)[0] + '\' + f`? Otherwise the `\\` is going to be treated as an operator, right?

Comment: we should even double the backslash `...+ '\\' +...`, or use `os.path.join(os.path.splitext(f)[0],f)`

Comment: @PRMoureu I like the `os.path.join` method. Thank you for the answer.